# Heat Losses to furnaces

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, thermal-conductivity, cooling

I am looking in to the thermal efficiency of a furnace vessel. I am wanting to get a full, or at least better, understanding on the calculations needed to look at the thermal efficiency.

So I know the burner kW rating i.e. The energy going in to the furnace. I need to work out how much heat is lost to the wall (cylindrical), base, door, flue gap (hole in door) and there is also a small gap between the door and the vessel.

- How do I calculate the heat loss for infiltration of cold air from the door gap. And;
- How do I account for the exfiltration of hot air through the flue?

I have completed heat loss calculations to the walls, but if you have any advice or knowledge on that, it would also be appreciated. in summary, I know the K values for refractory, temperature gradients, thickness of refractories, thermal restivity, area of furnace refractory, and I have calculated Q (heat loss) from these.

Comment: Or... you could simply measure the heat that comes out and then take the ratio. That's what a physicist would do. It's also what an engineer would do.

Comment: I am not sure how to go about measuring the heat that comes out? I don't have any sort of emission temp gauge unfortunately

Comment: Temperature has woefully little to do with efficiency. If you can't do these measurements, how would you ever check if your calculations are even in the ballpark?

Comment: what's the best way to measure the 'heat that comes out'? my intention was to do a theoretical based calculation and in future take measurements (just not at this time)

Comment: What is your furnace doing? Heating water or steam? Then you have to measure the flow rate and the difference between inlet and outlet temperature. If all you are interested in is the internal temperature, then efficiency is not really important, only total power consumption to achieve that temperature. Either way, you have to have a measurable "output" that you want to achieve to judge if your input makes any sense.

Comment: this furnace is for melting an iron based material. It has a refractory brick internal wall

Comment: In that case you can calculate the rate at which it can melt the material and multiply with the necessary amount of heat to melt it.